# How can I read 10-bit Raw image? which contain RGB-IR data

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, image-processing

I want to know how extract the rgb image from my 10-bit raw (it has rgb-ir imagedata) data?

How can I read in Python or MATLAB?

The camera resolution at the time of capture were 1280x720:
indoor photo [Image for download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0givAGTBMIweWMzbWFzd0xSQ2M/view?usp=sharing) 
outdoor photo [Image 2 for download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0givAGTBMIwSkVJT1B5bHJoYkk?usp=sharing)

camera Model: e-CAM40_CUMI4682_MOD

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the format or layout of a 10-bit image?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ if you want to know how to read the image using Python or Matlab?  Did you know that C++ is a different language than Python?

Comment: ouh thanks for that, I'm beginner here

Comment: Why have you uploaded an executable file as the camera description - nobody will run that.

Comment: I can't seem to make your numbers work. You have 921,600 pixels if your image is 1280x720. Your file is 1,843,200 bytes, so you appear to have 2 bytes per pixel, or 16 bits per pixel. How does that relate to your stated 10 bits per pixel? Is there RGB in there as well as IR? If so, is the RGB in 6 bits or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the information I will check, sorry I am beginner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used the following image processing stages:

- Bayer mosaic color channel separation.
- Linear stretching each color channel.
- Simple white balance.
- Replace IR color channel with green (convert image to standard Bayer format).
- Restore Bayer mosaic.
- Simple gamma correction.
- Demosaic

Instead of processing the IR color channel, I replaced it with green color channel.

According to the RGB image you added, I found the [CFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array) order.
The CFA (color filter array) order is:

```
B | G
-- --
IR| R
```

The following Matlab code process the image to RGB:

```matlab
srcN = 1280;
srcM = 720;

f = fopen('image_raw.raw', 'r');

%Read as transposed matrix dimensions, and transpose the matrix.
%The reason for that, is that Matlab memory oreder is column major, and
%raw image is stored in row major (like C arrays).
I = fread(f, [srcN, srcM], 'uint16');
fclose(f);
I = I';

%Convert from range [0, 1023] range [0, 1] (working in double image format).
I = I/(2^10-1);

%Bayer mosaic color channel separation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Assume input format is GBRG Bayer mosaic format.
%Separate to color components.
B = I(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
G = I(1:2:end, 2:2:end);
IR = I(2:2:end, 1:2:end);
R = I(2:2:end, 2:2:end);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Linear stretching each color channel.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Linear streatch blue color channel.
B = imadjust(B, stretchlim(B, [0.02 0.98]),[]);

%Linear streatch green channel.
G = imadjust(G, stretchlim(G, [0.02 0.98]),[]);

%Linear streatch red color channel.
R = imadjust(R, stretchlim(R, [0.02 0.98]),[]);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Simple white balance
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Median or R, G and B.
rgb_med = [median(R(:)), median(G(:)), median(B(:))];
rgb_scale = max(rgb_med)./rgb_med;

%Scale each color channel, to have the same median.
R = R*rgb_scale(1);
G = G*rgb_scale(2);
B = B*rgb_scale(3);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Restore Bayer mosaic.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Insert streached color channnels back into I.
I(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = B;
I(1:2:end, 2:2:end) = G;
%I(2:2:end, 1:2:end) = G; %Replace IR with Green.
I(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = R;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Replace IR with green - resize green to full size of image first.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
T = imresize(G, [srcM, srcN]); %T - temporary green, size 1280x720
I(2:2:end, 1:2:end) = T(2:2:end, 1:2:end); %Replace IR with Green.
I = max(min(I, 1), 0); %Limit I to range [0, 1].
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Simple gamma correction
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
gamma = 0.45;
I = I.^gamma;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Demosaic
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Convert to uint8 (range [0, 255]).
I = uint8(round(I*255));
RGB = demosaic(I, 'bggr');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

imshow(RGB);
```

Result:

[image]

Now the colors are normal...

---

**Outdoor image processing :**

Applying "indoor" processing on the outdoor image, gets the following result:

[image]

White trees is a sign for Near-IR spectrum penetration to R, G and B pixels (not only to IR pixels).
The chlorophyll of the vegetation has high reflection in the Near-IR spectrum.  See: [http://missionscience.nasa.gov/ems/08_nearinfraredwaves.html‌​](http://missionscience.nasa.gov/ems/08_nearinfraredwaves.html%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B), and search it on Google.
Subtracting IR from Red, Green and Blue color channels is required.

---

I used the following image processing stages:

- Bayer mosaic color channel separation.
- **Subtract IR "surplus" from Red, Green and Blue color channels.**
- Linear stretching each color channel.
- Simple white balance.
- Restore Bayer mosaic.
- Simple gamma correction.
- Demosaic.
- Resize RGB image to lower resolution.

The following Matlab code process the outdoor image to RGB:

```matlab
srcN = 1280;
srcM = 720;

f = fopen('ir_6.raw', 'r');

%Read as transposed matrix dimensions, and transpose the matrix.
%The reason for that, is that Matlab memory oreder is column major, and
%raw image is stored in row major (like C arrays).
I = fread(f, [srcN, srcM], 'uint16');
fclose(f);
I = I';

%Convert from range [0, 1023] range [0, 1] (working in double image format).
I = I/(2^10-1);

%Bayer mosaic color channel separation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Assume input format is GBRG Bayer mosaic format.
%Separate to color components.
B = I(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
G = I(1:2:end, 2:2:end);
IR = I(2:2:end, 1:2:end);
R = I(2:2:end, 2:2:end);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Subtract IR "surplus" from R, G and B.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%The coefficients were tuned by trial and error...
ir_r = 1.3;  % 130% of IR radiation is absorbed by red pixels??? 
ir_g = 0.35; % 35% of IR radiation is absorbed by green pixels.
ir_b = 0.3;  % 30% of IR radiation is absorbed by blue pixels.

IR = imresize(IR, size(I)); %Resize IR to the size of I.
IR = max(min(IR, 1), 0); %Limit IR to range [0, 1] (because imresize values slightly outside the range of input).

R = R - IR(2:2:end, 2:2:end)*ir_r; %Subtract IR for R (IR scale coefficient is ir_r).
G = G - IR(1:2:end, 2:2:end)*ir_g; %Subtract IR for G (IR scale coefficient is ir_g).
B = B - IR(1:2:end, 1:2:end)*ir_b; %Subtract IR for B (IR scale coefficient is ir_b).

R = max(min(R, 1), 0); %Limit IR to range [0, 1] 
G = max(min(G, 1), 0);
B = max(min(B, 1), 0);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Linear stretching each color channel.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Linear streatch blue color channel.
B = imadjust(B, stretchlim(B, [0.02 0.98]),[]);

%Linear streatch green channel.
G = imadjust(G, stretchlim(G, [0.02 0.98]),[]);

%Linear streatch red color channel.
R = imadjust(R, stretchlim(R, [0.02 0.98]),[]);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Simple white balance
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Median or R, G and B.
rgb_med = [median(R(:)), median(G(:)), median(B(:))];
rgb_scale = max(rgb_med)./rgb_med;

%Scale each color channel, to have the same median.
R = R*rgb_scale(1);
G = G*rgb_scale(2);
B = B*rgb_scale(3);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Restore Bayer mosaic.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Insert streached color channnels back into I.
I(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = B;
I(1:2:end, 2:2:end) = G;
I(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = R;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Replace IR with green - resize green to full size of image first.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
T = imresize(G, [srcM, srcN]); %T - temporary green, size 1280x720
I(2:2:end, 1:2:end) = T(2:2:end, 1:2:end); %Replace IR with Green.
I = max(min(I, 1), 0); %Limit I to range [0, 1].
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Simple gamma correction
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
gamma = 0.45;
I = I.^gamma;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Demosaic
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Convert to uint8 (range [0, 255]).
I = uint8(round(I*255));
RGB = demosaic(I, 'bggr');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

RGB = imresize(RGB, size(I)/2); %Shrink size of RGB image for reducing demosaic artifacts.

imshow(RGB);
```

Result is not so good, but it demonstrates the concept that IR channel can be subtracted from the Red Green and Blue channels.
There is still work to be done...
Result image:

[image]

Reason for the "false color" green patches:
Saturated pixels in the Red color channel (saturated in the raw input), are not handled properly.
Problem can by solved by reducing exposure (taking the shot with lower exposure time).

Comment: Actually I missed the IR color channel. There is still work to be done...

Comment: So thank you, I will check and improve the ir and rgb images.
The image in rgb is like this one [click here to see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0givAGTBMIwc2ctYlI0SXhZWDg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you by the feedback , My big error,  the image which I added in the comment above is captured with other camera this is the image captured with the same camera (See3CAM_CU40), [Click to see image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0givAGTBMIwU0VNcjRZUXpRYnc/view?usp=sharing) I suppose it could be g|b::r|ir ?

Comment: I found a way to restore the colors.

Comment: Thanks so much but Did you have read any Article? to do this, if so Could you share with me?

Comment: My job involves raw video processing, so I was able to "improvise" a solution. The above solution is kind of "ad hoc" processing pipeline I created - this is not an academic solution. All the information is on the Web, you can start from Wikipedia: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format).

Comment: @Rotem While it was obvious to me, that this is something you did before, i'm still kind of amazed by your work. Good job!

Comment: Thanks Rotem, it's working very good with indoor photos but last Friday I took outdoor photos and it is not working enough good with this kind of photos. What do you think I have to do?

Comment: You can post an outdoor photo, and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks Rotem I have updated the question. And on indoor photos, to your code, I have added matrix color correction, because in green images I didn't get a good green color. this is the matrix which i have used: k =[3.240178 -0.969303 0.055644;...
    -1.537008 1.876083 -0.204027;...
    -0.498489 0.041558 1.057233];
Regards

Comment: Outdoor photo is looking grate... white trees is a sign for Near-IR spectrum penetration to R, G and B pixels (not only to IR pixels). The chlorophyll of the vegetation has high reflection in the Near-IR spectrum. See: [http://missionscience.nasa.gov/ems/08_nearinfraredwaves.html](http://missionscience.nasa.gov/ems/08_nearinfraredwaves.html), and search it on Google.

Comment: The CCM matrix (color correction matrix) you added will not help you solving the white trees problem. There must be a way to subtract the IR channel from R, G and B (with different weights). Solution can be 4x4 CCM matrix (for R,G,B,IR) instead of standard 3x3 CCM matrix. I have no idea how to produce 4x4 CCM matrix...

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try subtracting the IR channel from RGB

Comment: Dear @Rotem, I have been working in RGB color restoration from images with Nir infections. Right now I have a lot of images in raw, I do not have enough experience with images acquired with a single sensor camera.  I do not know if you have time but I think we can write a paper about this problem. What do you think?  if yes please check my profile [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5778441/xavier-soria-poma-xavysp?tab=profile) to contact me, or how can I contact you?

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I am not interested writing papers, I am a programmer (mostly implement algorithms defined by other persons). Sorry for asking, but can you please mark my answer as "accepted" (press the green V).

Comment: Yes sure Thanks for all.

Comment: @Rotem, Please the last question.
Could you explain me with more details this codes?
%The coefficients were tuned by trial and error...
ir_r = 1.3;  % 130% of IR radiation is absorbed by red pixels??? 
ir_g = 0.35; % 35% of IR radiation is absorbed by green pixels.
ir_b = 0.3;  % 30% of IR radiation is absorbed by blue pixels.
I cannot find this NIR subtraction method on web

Comment: @XavierSoriaPomaxavysp **1.** The subtraction method I used must be wrong, because 130% absorbed by red pixels is physically not possible. **2.** Think about it as combination of pixel [Quantum Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_efficiency) characteristics (same characteristics for all color channels) and [Color Filter Array] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array) characteristics (different characteristics for each color channel). Each CFA filter has different NIR transparency characteristics. Looks like red is more IR transparent than other channels.

Comment: @XavierSoriaPomaxavysp Each color filter, filters some of the NIR photons, and passes some of the NIR photons. In order to measure only the green photons in a green filtered pixel, you need to subtract NIR photons absorbed by the pixel surface (beneath green filter). **This is my way thinking of the problem (I suppose you are not going to find it on the WEB).**

Comment: what's the equivalent of matlab "demosaic" function in python?

Comment: I don't have much Python experience. I Guess using OpenCV is the standard solution.