# How can I read the RGB 10 bit raw image?

Tags: python, image, matlab, rgb, pixel

I have read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623001/how-can-i-read-10-bit-raw-image-which-contain-rgb-ir-data) with a similar question, but actually doesn't work for me. His image's resolution is 1280x720, file size is 1,843,200 bytes. The camera store 10 bits meta data into 16 bits space for each pixel. Although it is not containing true 16 bits data, but a linear stretching can do the job. What a real 10-bit format raw image is probably encoded like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvfrY.png).

My raw image is from OV5670 camera and output format is red in R1C2 (GRBG, not 100% sure, the driver is set in that way). Resolution is 1920x1080, size of the file: 2,592,000 bytes. Each pixel is exactly 10 bits.

Question: How can I decode it with Matlab or Python? The main problem is I don't know how the pixels are arranged as the specification didn't mention the pixels are in 2d array or 1d array.

[Download the raw file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LYEo0KAmhET2JZNDQwa3NmWFRERHpOQVJZSjNhb3o2SVM4/view?usp=sharing). (The driver doesn't have exposure control feature, the actual image might be over exposure)

EDITED: Here is the correct image from imatest software[image]

The structure of the sensor pixel is:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║  B G  ║  ...  ║       ║ 8 act ║
║  G R  ║  ...  ║       ║ dummy ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  ...  ║       ║       ║ 1944  ║
║  ...  ║       ║       ║ active║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║       ║       ║       ║ 8 act ║
║       ║       ║       ║ dummy ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║       ║       ║       ║  20   ║
║       ║       ║       ║  blk  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║16 act ║ 2592  ║ 16    ║       ║
║ dummy ║active ║ dummy ║       ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I have the datasheet but it is confidential. The pixel is format like my graph above. Act means active lines, blk means black lines. The subsampling is using 2x2 binning.

The datasheet is confidential and there is no public doc on internet. I posted a little portion about it hopefully

Answer (score 2):

I used this [OV5620 datasheet](http://electronics123.net/amazon/datasheet/OV5620_CLCC_DS%20(1.3).pdf) for reference and assumed that the same should be applicable for OV5670. The sheet states that the encoding is 10 bit per pixel which I was able to read directly in matlab with fread(). Also I followed BGGR format as mentioned in the sheet. Then using simple demosaic and scaling I was able to read the image :

```
% Reading
r = 1920;
c = 1080;

fin = fopen('v4l2srcnew03.raw');
I = fread(fin,r*c,'*ubit10');
I_r = reshape(I,r,c);

% Demosaic
I_d = demosaic(I_r,'bggr');

% Scale
I_d_r = mat2gray(I_d(:,:,1));
I_d_g = mat2gray(I_d(:,:,2));
I_d_b = mat2gray(I_d(:,:,3));
I_bggr_rgb = cat(3,I_d_r,I_d_g,I_d_b);
imshow(I_bggr_rgb)
```

The result is a bit grainy image but I think it can be improved appropriately by a better interpolation during demosiacing step or smoother scaling. Also you can try RGGB format if this is not the right color pattern.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit the syntax of I_d(:,:,1)? What does the comma do?

Comment: demosaic() returns a 3 dimensional unscaled matrix I_d. I_d(:,:,1) means all rows and all columns of I_d but only in the first channel which is the 'red' color channel. demosaic() while interpolating generates some values > 2^10 and also for proper visualization the generated matrix needs to be scaled (either between 0-1 for double or 0-256 for uint8). That is what I am trying to do by using mat2gray() on each color channel separately. Then I concatenate them back along the channels using cat(3,...)

Comment: However, I just tried to use some software to see the result, it appears different with the photo generated by the code. Is there any further work need to be done? I don't think the scaling or demosaic would produce that much noise.

Comment: Looks like some of my assumptions from the datasheet might be wrong. I will take a look at the code again.